# Error creating hive table from avro schema

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to create a hive table by extracting the schema from Avro data which is stored in s3. Data is stored in s3 using the s3 Kafka connector. I am publishing a simple POJO to the producer.

Code for extracting the schema from the Avro data:-

```
for filename in os.listdir(temp_folder_path):
    filename = temp_folder_path + filename
        if filename.endswith('avro'):
            os.system(
                'java -jar /path/to/avro-jar/avro-tools-1.8.2.jar getschema {0} > {1}'.format(
                filename, filename.replace('avro', 'avsc')))
```

The extracted schema is then saved in an s3 bucket.

Create table query:-

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db_name_service.table_name_change_log` PARTITIONED BY (`year` bigint,
 `month` bigint, `day` bigint, `hour` bigint) ROW FORMAT SERDE 
 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe' STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 
 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat' LOCATION 's3://bucket/topics/topic_name' 
 TBLPROPERTIES ( 'avro.schema.url'='s3://bucket/schemas/topic_name.avsc')
```

Error:-

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerdeException Schema for table must be of type RECORD. Received type: BYTES)
```

Schema:-

```
{ "type": "record", "name": "Employee", "doc" : "Represents an Employee at a company", "fields": [ {"name": 
"firstName", "type": "string", "doc": "The persons given name"}, {"name": "nickName", "type": ["null",
 "string"], "default" : null}, {"name": "lastName", "type": "string"}, {"name": "age", "type": "int",
  "default": -1}, {"name": "phoneNumber", "type": "string"} ] }
```

I can see data in the topics using this command `./confluent-4.1.1/bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --topic test2_singular --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning`

```
{"firstName":"A:0","nickName":{"string":"C"},"lastName":"C","age":0,"phoneNumber":"123"}

{"firstName":"A:1","nickName":{"string":"C"},"lastName":"C","age":1,"phoneNumber":"123"}
```

Comment: Your python code is looping a local filesystem files... What does this have to do with S3? In other words, you need to extract the schema from the S3 Avro files, no? Also, are you able to query this S3 data using Spark's Avro packages?

Comment: Also, can you please edit the question to include the Kafka Connect configuration?

Comment: @cricket_007 Problem was with my s3 connector properties. I have to change the value.converter to AvroConverter instead of default ByteArrayConverter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Schema for table must be of type RECORD. Received type: BYTES

The only way this could happen would be if you aren't using AvroConverter for the Connect sink configuration.

You'll also want to extract the schema from an S3 file.

Tip: using a Lambda function to watch for avro file creations in the bucket can help with getting schemas without scanning the entire bucket or random files *and* be used to notify Hive/AWS Glue table schema updates

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the lambda function? Should I extend some Avro for this or what?

Comment: See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/data-lake-ingestion-automatically-partition-hive-external-tables-with-aws/